# How to handle two login forms for different user types?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app has two types of users, Staff and Students. The Staff users have a different login page from the Student's. The problem is if I enter the email id and password of a student into login page of a staff, it gets logged in which should not be the case. Also I want to make clear that the staff cannot register with the app. They can only login with an email id and password provided to them so that students are not able to register as staff. This email id and password is created manually in auth console. But the auth does not have any specification for different users hence, even the email and password of students stored in auth is accepted by the staff login page. I am not sure how to handle the staff login in this case. Any help is appreciated.

This is the staff login:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful() ){
                        pd.dismiss();

                        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);



                    }else if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You are not allowed to login!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have in your database 2 different sections, `Staff` and `Students`. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
     |
     --- Staff
     |     |
     |     --- staff1@email,com
     |     |       |
     |     |       --- //details
     |     |
     |     --- staff2@email,com
     |             |
     |             --- //details
     |
     --- Students
           |
           --- student1@email,com
           |       |
           |       --- //details
           |
           --- student2@email,com
                   |
                   --- //details
```

As you probably see, the unique identifier between users is the email address. Then just use the `exists()` method on each section. If the user is a student and exists in `Students` section, then login, else show a message.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem is the staff is not allowed to register. They can only login with the provided email and password. Hence no data about them is being stored through the app inside the database unlike students login wherein when they register the details about them is also added up to the database. I am not sure how to store data for staff in the database manually.

Comment: Then don't allow the staff to register. In this case just use Firebase console to add the stuff. It's very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

> Please you must provide Unique token to Staff while Login or Registering into Application.
>
> For Ex:-
> Staff Login :-

1. Username
2. Password
3. Auth Token

> Student Login:-
> Student register normally with username and password.

1. Username.
2. Password.

> Auth token provide the difference between staff and student..

Comment: Thank u for replying. can you please tell me how to do that?